# Getting incorrect output for a basic multiplication in my C programme

Tags: c, math

I'm new to learning C, and practicing some basic code.
I keep getting either a 0 or a very large random number for the bill multiplication at the end. I think I've narrowed it down to an issue with my "quant" value but I can't figure it out. Here's the first part of the programme (that only calculates for the pizza options so far):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int num, cho, quant, bill;

printf("Select a number from the menu:\n1. Pizza\n2. Burger\n3. Sandwiches\n4. 
Beverages \n");
scanf("%d",&num);

if(num==1)
{
    printf("Select a number for the food you want to order, and the quantity. \n");
printf("1. Pepperoni\t\tRs 1000 \n2. Fajita\t\tRs 1000\n3. Hot n spicy\t\tRs 1100\n4. 
Chicken Tikka\tRs 1200\n");
scanf("%d,%d",&cho,&quant);
{
    if(cho==1)
cho=1000;
else if(cho==2)
cho=1000;
else if(cho==3)
cho=1100;
else if(cho==4)
cho=1200;
    
}
bill=cho*quant;
printf("Please take your food item(s). Total bill = Rs %d \nThank you.",bill);
    
}

getchar();
getchar();
getchar(); getchar(); getchar();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You aren't checking if your `scanf()` functions actually read anything.  `scanf()` returns the number of items it successfully read for a reason...

Comment: I don't think you want a comma in your formatting string for your `scanf`.

Comment: I finally see that now. Thanks!

Comment: Please indent your code to be easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The way you have your `scanf` for cho and quant right now expects the user to enter two numbers separated by nothing but a comma, i.e. `2,10`. If you do that format of input, your code works fine. However, if this format is broken the `scanf` does not properly read in a number to one or both of your variables, and they are left unitialized with potentially garbage information in them (hence the really large random numbers you're seeing).

You should probably change that line to

```
scanf("%d%d",&cho,&quant)
```

Comment: Ohh gosh, so silly of me. Thank you, that was it.